# How to explain the differences in these nested Visual Studio projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I am new to .Net and Visual Studio. In order to learn more, I decided to create a simple asp.Net application in my spare time. In Visual Studio I am trying to follow the same project structure as the application I support at work. I noticed that my work application has the following project structure

```
Development
|_services
  |_RedSun.Onvia
    |_various VS project folders (i.e. RedSun.Onvia.Core, RedSun.Onvia.Web, etc)
  |_RedSun.Onvia.sln
  |_RedSun.Onvia.v12.suo
```

Notice how the VS solution files are on the same level as the RedSun.Onvia solution folder. However when I create a basic empty project Visual Studio, it gives me the following structure...

```
Development
|_services
  |_RedSun.Onvia
    |_RedSun.Onvia.sln
    |_RedSun.Onvia.v12.suo
```

Note the RedSun.Onvia.sln and RedSun.Onvia.v12.suo files are a directory deeper than the solution folder. When I tried moving files around manually with File Explorer to try and match the structure above I was unable to open the project in VS due to errors.

Can anyone please explain how I can get the same structure as shown in the first example?

Comment: Move the .sln to _services, edit the .sln file and change the paths to the .csproj files